# Show subcategories within the catalogue

Tags: category

I'm still very new to Magento so some things may seem very obvious to you, but to me I haven't pieced it all together yet.

I have a task to show product categories in the left section of the screen, which I have managed successfully. But the product structure is very complex and there are sub-categories within sub-categories within sub-categories within sub-categories.

By default, when clicking a category/subcategory within the left menu, it seems to display all products underneath the clicked category/subcategory. I need the catalogue to show the subcategories on the clicked category/subcategory.

What are some pointers in learning how to do this? I'm not asking for a step-by-step on doing this, although feel free to provide that if you feel it necessary.

Many thanks, Ste

Comment: with the use of this link you can reach to your destimation

http://shahkeyul.wordpress.com/2013/03/31/how-to-get-all-category-and-sub-category-in-navigation-menu-dynamically-in-magento/

Comment: use only fetching data code and make what u want

Comment: Ste,if donot want  to sub category product at category then just make sub category as NON-achor category.

Comment: got admin>select a category and to it display setting tab Make Anchor field to no

Comment: I have now turned 'is anchor' to no and that seems to have disabled showing all products (shows a blank page) within the subcategory in the catalogue, which is good.

But now I need the page to show the sub categories when clicking the category/subcategory in the left menu. Do I need to write some code to achieve this?